# Unknown storage interactions during benchmarking custom pallet

Tags: pallet, storage, benchmarking

I was running benchmarks for my pallet and i had a note about some unknown db interactions besides the ones i expect.
`// Storage: unknown [0x3a7472616e73616374696f6e5f6c6576656c3a] (r:1 w:1)`
I tried to inspect this and surrounded storage keys and got this

[image]

I can't understand this key definition. But it seems to be related to ascii table in some way. Especially this order `:;<=>?`. What is this and what can cause these db queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the storage key for `:transaction_level:`. It is just ASCII encoded as HEX.
That key should be white-listed which is also the case on current Substrate master.
Your problem should be solved by updating Substrate. The change happened [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11394).

As context:
This key tracks how many transactional levels are currently stacked upon the storage overlay.
Each time an extrinsic is dispatched, its changes are stored to a temporary transactional level, such that the changes can be rolled back if the extrinsic fails. See [Substrate/#11918](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11918) for more.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the goal of disturbing especially `0x3a7472616e73616374696f6e5f6c6576656c3a`?

Comment: I added some context about the key.